# Where to place some domain logic methods in cqrs?

Tags: architecture, cqrs

I'm learning about the CQRS architectual pattern, but I'm a little confused. Where in this pattern must I place methods which don't query and don't command the database?

I'm talking about methods like `CalculateSomething()` or `IsPrimeNumber()` for example.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm learning about the CQRS architectual pattern, but I'm a little confused. Where in this pattern must I place methods which don't query and don't command the database?

"Query" in CQRS, doesn't necessarily mean "database query" in the sense of reading information persisted in another process; it could simply mean asking a question about the state of data in memory, without changing it.

```
X {
    boolean isPrimeNumber();
}
```

That's a query about the state of X, so it would be part of the read model.

```
X {
    T calculateSomething(Args...);
}
```

That's also going to be a query; and therefore part of the read model.